# ERR! 426 Upgrade Required, when I interact with the npm registry

Tags: npm

When I try to publish a new package to npm or try to logout, I get the following error message:

```
npm ERR! code E426
npm ERR! 426 Upgrade Required
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to npm websites and the npm
> registry—including for package installation—must use TLS 1.2 or
> higher.

[Source](https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/)

**What I did:**

- upgrade Node (0) to its current recommended version: 14.18.0 LTS
- upgrade npm with `npm install -g npm@latest`

**Solution:** I had to manually set the registry to use https instead of http as well:

- `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

---

(0) When using nvm, that's what you need to do:

```
nvm install 14.18.0
nvm use 14.18.0
nvm alias default 14.18.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much @robin-wieruch! you saved me hours of searching.

Comment: Updating the registry to use `https` was all that was needed :)

Comment: as others said setting registry to `HTTPS` with `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

setting `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` worked for me using npm v8