# google cloud - slow npm install for @wordpress/scripts

Tags: node.js, wordpress, npm, google-cloud-platform

I tried to run this command on linux on google cloud . I am on node v14.21.3 and npm 9.7.2

`npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev`

but it gets stuck at `fetchMetadata:` and become very slow .

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433130/npm-install-gets-stuck-at-fetchmetadata) and as mentioned in top answer , I did

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global
npm cache clear --force
npm install --verbose @wordpress/scripts --save-dev`
```

and got this error

```
(#########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠇ reify:fsevents: verb audit error HttpErrorGeneral: 426 Upgrade Required - POST http://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick
```

I looked around and based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448082/err-426-upgrade-required-when-i-interact-with-the-npm-registry) , I set the registry  as

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and also did  `npm cache clear --force`

and ran command `npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev` again and now I get

```
ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/travel/node_modules/babel-loader' -> '/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/travel/node_modules/.babel-loader-P0fx9R40'
```

I tried to remove node_modules by running `npm remove node_modules` but I still get

```
ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/travel/node_modules/babel-loader' -> '/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/travel/node_modules/.babel-loader-P0fx9R40'
```

How do I resolve this and install `@wordpress/scripts` using npm and  how do I make sure that I do not get this kind of issues. Is there something missing in npm and node setup ?

**UPDATE::** I tried to run again after doing `rm -rf node_modules` the installation did not even reach error , it is so slow that it only reach this and then stuck at that point

```
....
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/estree/-/estree-1.0.1.tgz 225800ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob-to-regexp/-/glob-to-regexp-0.4.1.tgz 227046ms (cache miss)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tmpl/-/tmpl-1.0.5.tgz 227349ms (cache miss)
```

**UPDATE2::**. I also tried this `npm set maxsockets 3` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433130/npm-install-gets-stuck-at-fetchmetadata)
but the installation gets stuck at
`reify:postcss-safe-parser: timing reifyNode:node_modules/svg-tags`

Also I tried downgrading to npm 6 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893199/hanging-stuck-reifyprettier-timing-reifynodenode-modules-nrwl-workspace-comp) but it gets stuck at
 `fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule devtools-protocol@0.0.981744 checking installable status`

**UPDATE3::**
I tried with fresh install of nvm, npm and node but it did not help either. Also I tried using `npm config set strict-ssl true` but that  also didn't help and `npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev`  was slow and is still running for half hour .

**UPDATE4::**
On a different compute engine instance( on which I do not have apache2 , wordpress and ssl)  I was able to run `npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev` successfully and it took 5 minutes to install the package

Is there a way to debug this without having to start from scratch like reinstalling everything again and checking in between for `npm install` and see which installation is causing the slowness ?

can someone please help?

Comment: Do you have an anti virus running perhaps? I've seen them interfere with `npm install`s by taking locks on files when being renamed. Also, try reinstalling npm (updating Node.js is probably the easiest way)

Comment: I switched node versions using nvm and used 18.16.1 and then ran `npm remove node_modules` but still the same above error . My npm is 9.5.1 .  I am not sure how to know if there is  antivirus running as I am doing all this  on VM instance in google cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the solutions  that I linked above or found elsewhere did not worked for me. The only thing worked was to install everything again on a new google cloud instance. This time I purposefully increased the RAM( not saying that RAM was the issue but I just increased it).  I installed Apache , PHP , MySQL , Wordpress again and then installed node, npm and did `npm install @wordpress/scripts --save-dev` , it worked and took about a min to install the package.